# ServiceHub.DataWarehousrHost

Tags: visual-studio, память

Столкнулся с проблемой. Visual Studio потребляет огромное кол-во памяти. Попеременно процессы DataWarehouseHost, Roslyn.CodeAnalysisService, Host.CLR.x64. В сумме расход может превышать 2ГБ (проект не запущен). Даже все в округе начинает лагать.
От проекта не зависит. Visual Studio 2019 v16.10
В интернетах ничего внятного. Предлагают отключить все анализы кода, CodeLens, Live-тестирования. Это никак не помогло.
Может кто-то сталкивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Будь проклят тот день когда я сел за баранку этого пылесоса (VS)

Comment: Установите Visual Studio 6, все будет летать) Но правда и современных возможностей не будет)

Comment: По той же логике я бы и Win XP использовал, быстрая и приятная=)))